# Can I use two switches on one mouse button?

Tags: soldering, mouse

I am doing a diy project where I replace the mouse switches with a mechanical switch.  I wish to wire two mechanical switches in parallel to a computer mouse left-click button. They will be wired in so that either switch will generate a mouse left-click and I would like to know if it is possible to do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: e.g. "I wish to wire two mechanical switches in parallel to a computer mouse left-click button. They will be wired in OR configuration so that either switch will generate a mouse left-click." Hit the [edit] link ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a standard push button that makes two contacts to close when button is closed, in theory it is possible to connect infinitely many buttons that all click the left mouse button.

Comment: so it's safe to do it?

Comment: I really have no idea what to answer to that. What do you mean by safety here?

Comment: Oh sorry, what I meant is that can I just simply connect the two same switches on one wire or is there a safer way?

Comment: I think each switch must have two wires connected to work. Just wire the switches in parallel. Do it in any way you think is safe.

Comment: Yep it has a wire connected to each of the pins of the switch. I didn't know that the wording is parallel hehe. Thank you very much!